# Service Broker process active for too long in SQL Sever

Tags: sql-server, performance, service-broker

Let me acknowledge, I don't know much about database efficiency neither Service Broker as a whole, where I work the dba that used tp handle these kind of things left some weeks ago. The company uses service broker to handle a bunch of requests, constantly. My concern is that there's a query (which is used in a service broker) that pulls data from a queue active for more than six days.

The query is something like:

```
    RECEIVE TOP (1)
        @vQueueData = CAST([message_body] AS NVARCHAR)
        ,@MessageType = [message_type_name]
    FROM
        broker.WhateverReceiveQueue
```

When I run `sp_whoisactive` I get something like this:
[image]

Is it normal or would this be affecting database's performance somehow? I have not received any news regarding performing issues, though.

If anyone can help to clear my doubts thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If SQL Server 2016 or better, [check this](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/10/sql-performance/service-broker-enhancements).

Comment: That looks like a service broker internal activation procedure, which should remain running so long as messages keep arriving on the queue within its coded timeout.  If it's coded to run forever in a loop in the absence of messages, then you might want to fix it.  But it's probably not a huge deal.  Can you post the entire text of the batch that is running in an edit to your question?

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's SQL Server 2016 SP1. Thanks for the link, will check.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes it is an activation procedure, that text I posted in my comment it's pretty much everything that there was in the sql_text field of the `sp_whoisactive` output. I only changed some names. I didn't get pretty clear where I should look for to verify if it should run like a loop for ever.

Comment: If it's an internal activation procedure you can look at the body of the stored procedure.  You can find the name by running `select name, activation_procedure 
from sys.service_queues
where is_activation_enabled = 1`

Comment: I've just checked, the stored procedure does not even iterate in anything. But I guess the process is active for so long because of what you said in the your first comment. I will assume it's working as expected. There are many others services brokers in our company but I only see this one active for so long.